# uwp inheriting from base page giving compile errors

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, navigation, uwp

I am trying to inherit from a base page instead of Normal `Page` control of XAML but Visual Studio is giving me compile time errors that `OnNavigatedTo method not found to be overridden`.

I am doing this because I have multiple pages with a lot of similar code and I want to write that code just once, so I want to write that code in parent class and then inherit all pages from that parent class, I followed guidelines as stated on multiple resources on internet and below is my code.

**Parent Class:**

```
public class VideoParentPage : Page
{
}
```

**Child Class (AllVideoPage.xaml.cs):**

```
public sealed partial class AllVideosPage : VideoParentPage
{
    public AllVideosPage() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetBanner();
    }
}
```

**XAML in file AllVideosPage.xaml:**

```
<local:VideoParentPage
    xmlns:local="using:Fluent_Video_Player.Views.Shared"
    ...some unrelated XAML code...
</local:VideoParentPage>
```

**Note:** I have used all necessary using statement in C# classes.

Comment: When I use some base page for the first time I get similar errors. Have you tried compiling the app? Compiling always resolved these issues for me. Maybe try cleaning the solution and rebuilding it.

Comment: compiler shows errors but somehow app is able to run and works fine, until I add some methods to the parent class and try to use them in child class, and then all sorts of error occur, it doesn't even build then and it doesn't even recognize those variables ( which it was recognizing just fine moments ago)  and if I remove those functions from parent class and just use some variables, then they do show red lines and error in the editor, but app builds and runs just fine.

Comment: Well that's weird, after first compilation all the errors are always gone for me. You should try cleaning the solution `Build > Clean Solution` then closing VS, removing the remaining `bin` and `obj` folders and then try it again.

Comment: `VideoParentPage` is derived from `Page` class but it is empty?

Comment: no its not empty it has some code but that was irrelivent here so I showed it empty

Comment: @MarianDolinský thnks a lot please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try cleaning the solution `Build > Clean Solution`, closing VS, removing the remaining `bin` and `obj` folders and then compiling the app again.